# Mocha and chai - Error: timeout of 25000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, chai

I am to write a simple test using Mocha, Chai and selenium webdriver. But its throwing me:

> Error: timeout of 25000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is
>   being called in this test.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
'use strict';

var webdriver = require ('selenium-webdriver'),
  chai = require ('chai'),
  until = webdriver.until,
  By = webdriver.By,
  wait = webdriver.wait,
  chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised"),
  assert = chai.assert,
  mocha = require('mocha'),
  expect = chai.expect;
  chai.config.includeStack = true;

  var driver;

  describe('Login', function(){
      before(function(done){

        driver = new webdriver
          .Builder()
          .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
          .build();

        driver.get('http://someurl');
        driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys('username');
        driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys('password');
        driver.findElement(By.id('Login')).click();

        this.timeout(25000);
        setTimeout(done, 25000);

      });


      after(function(done){
        driver.quit();
        this.timeout(5000);
        done();
      });




      it('verify the waiting for task Button', function(){
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('.StartButton__btn')))
         .then(function(){
        driver.findElement(By.css('.StartButton__btn')).click();
      });

        var waitScreenTest = 
        driver.findElement(By.css('.WaitingScreen__text')).getText();
        assert(waitScreenTest, 'Waiting for Tasks');
      });
  });
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer to your question is "return your promises so that Mocha can wait for them".

However, `selenium-webdriver` provides wrappers around Mocha's stock functions. These functions hook into Selenium's promise machinery and obviate the need to return the promises or use the `done` callback to wait for Selenium's driver to be done. You just need to import `selenium-webdriver/testing` and then use the `describe`, `it`, `before`, `after`,... functions provided by that module.

```
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');

test.describe("top level", function () {

  test.before(...);

  test.it("some test", function () {
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But its giving me the same error even after using 'test'.